# Repmgr: Error to promote Standby Cluster to Master Cluster in failover

Tags: postgresql, clustering, failover, debian, repmgr

I maked the configuration of the failover system based in [Repmgr](https://repmgr.org/), but i don't haved success to promote the Standby Cluster to Master Cluster in case of failover.

Following my configurations, this process shoulded happens automatically, but does not works.

Additional Information:

- Debian 9.2, PostgresSQL 9.6, Repmgr 3.3
- IP Master (host1): 10.0.0.1, IP Standby (host2): 10.0.0.2
- Contents included in `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf`, the same for all

  ```
  wal_keep_segments = 5000
  hot_standby = on
  archive_mode = on
  listen_addresses = '*'
  max_wal_senders = 18
  wal_level = hot_standby
  shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr_funcs'
  archive_command = 'cd .'
  ```
- Contents of `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`

Master

```
    local   all             postgres                                peer
    local   all             all                                     peer
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    host    repmgr          repmgr          10.0.0.2/32             trust
    host    replication     repmgr          10.0.0.2/32             trust
```

Standby

```
    local   all             postgres                                peer
    local   all             all                                     peer
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    host    repmgr          repmgr          10.0.0.1/32             trust
    host    replication     repmgr          10.0.0.1/32             trust
```

- Contents of `/etc/repmgr.conf`

Master

```
    cluster=cluster
    node=1
    node_name=host1
    conninfo='host=host1 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2'
    failover=automatic
    promote_command='repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
    follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
    logfile='/var/log/postgresql/repmgr.log'
    loglevel=NOTICE
    reconnect_attempts=4
    reconnect_interval=5
```

Standby

```
    cluster=cluster
    node=2
    node_name=host2
    conninfo='host=host2 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2'
    failover=automatic
    promote_command='repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
    follow_command='repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
    logfile='/var/log/postgresql/repmgr.log'
    loglevel=NOTICE
    reconnect_attempts=4
    reconnect_interval=5
```

- Contents included in `/etc/default/repmgrd`, the same for all

  ```
  REPMGRD_ENABLED=yes
  REPMGRD_CONF="/etc/repmgr.conf"
  ```
- Result of `repmgr cluster show` command

  ```
  postgres@host1:~$ repmgr cluster show
  Role      | Name   | Upstream | Connection String
  ----------+--------|----------|--------------------------------------------------------
  * master  | host1  |          | host=host1 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
    standby | host2  | host1    | host=host2 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
  ```
- Error found in log file (/var/log/postgresql/repmgr.log) when executing command "repmgrd"

  ```
  [ERROR] unable to retrieve record for node 1: ERROR: relation "repmgr_cluster.repl_nodes" does not exist LINE 1: ...onninfo, slot_name, priority, active FROM "repmgr_cl...
  ```

Complete Tutorial: https://medium.com/@victor.boissiere/how-to-setup-postgresql-cluster-with-repmgr-febc2f10c243

Comment: error found in log file (/var/log/postgresql/repmgr.log) when executing command "repmgrd"
`[ERROR] unable to retrieve record for node 1: ERROR:  relation "repmgr_cluster.repl_nodes" does not exist
LINE 1: ...onninfo,        slot_name, priority, active  FROM "repmgr_cl...`

Comment: That looks like an important info, I would add it untruncated to the question

Answer (score 0):

check out this useful link :

•   http://raghavt.blogspot.in/2015/01/configuring-automatic-failover-using.html

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution/participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the answers posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I write a good answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (Help Centre)_ In the section **Answer the question** there is a short sentence which reads: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there_